# Setting up 2 reactjs applications using one node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I need to setup 2 ReactJS applications using one node.js server. The ReactJs applications where created using `create-react-app`.

The applications has different purposes, but will be runninng in the same user context. Both has their own routers (from `<Route>` component on `react-router`) and individual behaviour.

One application has a hyperlink for another application. Once the user clicks on the link, the other application is loaded, and the other way back.

I´m confusing about how to setup my server. Should I create two different routes 
 - like `app.use("/app1")` and `app.use("/app2")` ?

In development, should I run 2 webpack-dev-servers, something like (considering default create-react-app configuration):

```
$ npm start (for my server)
$ npm start (for my client1)
$ npm start (for my client2)
```

And in production, how to switch from one application to another ?

Is there a general "how to" in order to achieve that ?

Comment: Just create your server, with the necessary routes, and run your applications. There is no secret at all. Not sure if I understand `And in production, how to switch from one application to another ?` You should deploy both applications and consume your API from the server.

Comment: @TiagoAlves is right all you need to do is to set one backend who will serve 2 different clients using routs

Answer (score 0):

In dev, you are likely to customize `package.json` since you created with `create-react-app`. You are likely to [require proxies](https://dev.to/loujaybee/using-create-react-app-with-express).

In production, you can use an Express server to mount 2 different `router`s ([router docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router)) that employs routing logic and serve different static React generated files on different paths.

If your 2 apps use different domain name, try Express `vhost` module [(Github link)](https://github.com/expressjs/vhost).

If your 2 apps eventually need HTTPS, and you still want a single Node server, learn about [tlsServer.addContext()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/tls.html#tls_server_addcontext_hostname_context). Otherwise, you have to split it to 2 Node servers and need to use reverse proxy, employing `node-http-proxy` or `nginx`